# Establishing session variables and maintaining security on a web page

Tags: php, session

I've create a web site that authenticates users via LDAPS to a Windows domain - works fine, users are able to log in when they enter credentials a session variable ($_SESSION['LDAPSExampleUsername'] is established and maintained until they log out.  So, I want to make sure that if a user is logged in, they can see `https://host/main.php`.  If they're not logged in, they can't get to main.php, it'll just take them to `https://host` so that they can to log in.  I have this working fine with syntax like;

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['LDAPSExampleUsername']))
        {
        header("Location: /");die();
        }
```

I've been doing some reading and find that many say that this isn't really such a great idea because web browsers can disable forwarding to other web pages (defeating the purpose and causing a major issue).  What is the appropriate way of handling this situation?

Comment: i think this will not cause any problem

Comment: If this check goes in every page where authentication is needed then there is no way to bypass this without being logged in

Comment: Even if the header instruction is bypassed / disabled the die() instruction will still be executed and the rest of the script will not be executed (apart from a a few things, shutdown function's and destructor's) see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php (check the exit function)